# Conflict Css of jquery mobile while showing pop up screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image]I have one page and one pop up page i want to show pop up screen on clicking a button .I have header on both pop up screen and page but when i click the button the pop up is display but it css is not well as actual .
I am using jquery mobile .
Here is my fiddle

```
  <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Cases</h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting">Setting</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" >Add</a>
                <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog"id="Edit">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

</div>
     </div-->

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="here_table" >
            </ul>
            </div>

    </div>




    <!-- Page two  Case Information Screen-------------------------->  

    <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">

            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
            <h1>Case Information</h1>
            <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Add</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Case Date:</label>
            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: here is my code in fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/HesVd/3/

**What I've changed in your demo**

- I changed your HTML structure a lil bit :

  ```
  <div data-role="page" id="Home">
     <div data-role="header"></div>
     <div data-role="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen"></div>

                 |   |
                 |   |
                \     /
                 \   /
                  \ /

   <div data-role="page" id="Home">
     <div data-role="header"></div>
     <div data-role="content">
         <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  ```

The reason is because `popup` has to lie inside page. Only then will the styling remain.

- I removed the code you'd put for popup to fire and added it inline in the HTML like this:

  ```
     <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
  ```

Note that I've added only the changed attributes. The rest of the attributes are in demo.

Comment: @user2484319 what prblm are u facing?

Comment: @user2484319 can i know whats wrong with the answer so that i can correct it?

Comment: actually i added one background image behind the table view .But when i saw on Ipad the image is display it ok .But when i scroll the table the image show upto the size of ipad .if number of rows more than white background show after few row scrolling

Comment: You can add one background image on list .which display whole time till last row of table.i add one background but it show up to  few rows .then after white background display

Comment: Second issue  while scrolling click event is fire firstly then scrolling .If some user want to go to different screen on click row .But if if want to scroll row in between it goes to different screen.

Comment: Here is my first issue about background image. which is became smaller when list is large. http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/5/

Comment: check now @user2484319 : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/HesVd/7/
added some extra support for browsers.. also fixed the header to remain at the top even when u click..

Comment: Thanks...............But at browser everything looking fine .But when i saw on Ipad it show Black thing(some part) on header and footer .Ipad using safari ..? may bhi that problem

Comment: a screenshot would help a lot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31822/discussion-between-passionatecoder-and-user2484319)

Comment: whats the site? So that i can go check on the site itself

Comment: i am checking on ipad simulator. you can check on safari browser it show the same effect.

Comment: Check this issue on safari browser

Comment: I am facing more issue ..When i click setting or add Button it show pop up (in between i again click it is hide) Example if i click add button it show dialog then again i click setting button intend of showing setting popup it hide the first .I think whenever there is pop up screen it will disble all three buttons ? how to disable  button while showing  pop up.

Comment: Secondly whenever there is popup screen display .then user also able to scroll table view so pop up screen also scroll then it will also hiden.May be user not able to scroll if there is pop upscreen display.Here is my update code.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/8/